# ruby on rails- non-existent route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller file,

```
abc_controller.rb.
```

I have defined the show method inside it.

I have a view file,

```
show.html.haml
```

inside app/views/abc/

In my routes.rb file, I am giving the following command

```
resources :abc
```

I have a button

```
= link_to 'abc', abc_path, class: 'btn btn-default'
```

But when I click on the button, its not going to the new page.

I am getting non-existent route error. 
Since I am a newbie to rails, I am not able to figure what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, and the error is correct, there is indeed no such route.

Comment: Could you tel me how I can correct it?

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see all the available route prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a error because there is no such path as `abc_path`.  Run `rake routes` and you'll see the routes that Rails understands.  In you example,  `resources :abc` produces the following routes.

```
abc_index GET      /abc(.:format)            abc#index
          POST     /abc(.:format)            abc#create
  new_abc GET      /abc/new(.:format)        abc#new
 edit_abc GET      /abc/:id/edit(.:format)   abc#edit
      abc GET      /abc/:id(.:format)        abc#show
          PATCH    /abc/:id(.:format)        abc#update
          PUT      /abc/:id(.:format)        abc#update
          DELETE   /abc/:id(.:format)        abc#destroy
```

The first column are the named routes.  So in order to get to the `index` action of `abc_controller`, the route is named `abc_index_path`.  There is an `abc_path` but it needs an `id` params which means that you need to pass something to it.  In your case, there's no definitive value to pass to this method so as a trial just use `abc_path(1)` which will redirect you to `/abc/1`.  This goes to the show action with `params[:id]` set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `resources` (plural) the resulting route for show requires an id: `/abc/:id(.:format)`, so `abc_path` requires that you pass that :id or a object. If you are dealing with a singular abc (`resource :abc`), the resulting path doesn't require that :id, so you code should work (this is less common, but hard to tell with your "abc" example.